# Разгрузка сервера

Tags: сервер, клиент-сервер

Предполагается чрезмерно высокая нагрузка на сервер: каждый клиент может иметь по 20 соединений. Проблема, скорее всего, решается изменением концепции сервера.

Возможно ли вынести основную часть соединения с сервера на другое устройство? Просто, эта основная часть соединений представляет собой перенаправленный трафик - взаимодействие клиентов через третью сторону - сервер; сервер здесь должен только перенаправлять данные с одного сокета на другой. Думаю, эту задачу можно решить путём выноса такой работы на другое устройство. Может маршрутизатор какой?..

Хотелось бы поподробнее узнать у гуру как поступают в таких ситуациях)

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: Давайте рассмотрим на примере работы серверов TeamViewer: каждый клиент может иметь несколько соединений с другими клиентами используя сервер, но сам сервер эти соединения направляет на маршрутизатор (или как это там работает), чтобы избавится от излишней нагрузки.

Comment: Скорее всего, сервер предоставляет клиентам информацию друг о друге, чтобы они могли соединяться непосредственно друг с другом. Не знаю точно, как это делается, если клиенты за NAT провайдера. Вроде, VPN и IP6 такое позволяет. Да и BitTorrent работает же как-то. В принципе, если через маршрутизатор никак не пробраться (кастомная прошивка провайдера, которая запрещает включать проброс портов), то можно сделать много серверов. Один центральный, остальные коннектят клиентов между собой.

Comment: Вы правы, что клиенты в первую очередь стремятся соединиться непосредственно, но симметричный NAT не позволит использовать UDP/TCP Hole Punching уязвимость (остальные типы NAT, соответственно, позволяют). Много серверов? Тоже вариант. У TeamViewer, кстати, их действительно несколько. Но вот если почитать об алгоритмах соединения, то на офсайте TV есть упоминание о соединении через их "маршрутизатор". Могли ли они иметь ввиду несколько серверов под этим?

Comment: Пожалуй, могли. Когда вы комментируете свой вопрос без указания кому комментарий, пользователь не получает уведомления. Я вот чисто случайно сейчас вспомнил о вашем вопросе и зашел в него посмотреть, что нового. Так и увидел ваш комментарий.

Comment: @D.Stark начинайте сообщения с имени того, к кому обращаетесь: `@D.Stark текст сообщения...`

Comment: Чувак, где конкретика?) Непонятно, что ты хочешь, кто клиенты, что за сервер и тп. При правельной архитектуре не должно быть что сервер имеет 20 подключений от одного клиента или что клиент имеет 20 соединение от одного сервера. Скорее всего достаточно просто написать сигнальные сервер, но это не точная информация

Comment: Максимум, что могут стандартные маршрутизаторы - это выполнить NAT. в случае когда вам надо связать два входящих коннекта от разных пользователей это вам не поможет. Все что сможет сделать маршрутизатор в вашем случае - это выступить в роли балансировщика нагрузки и раскидать входящие соединения на пул обрабатывающих серверов.Но того ж можно добиться и другими средствами. Так что вас 2 отдельные задачи: обеспечить масштабируемость, т.е. разделение трафика на много серверов и максимально ускорить работу одного сервера (например вынеся код передачи трафика между соединениями в модуль ядра)